# Reinstall VMWare-Tools

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I have Ubuntu running on virtual machine and found that drag and dropping files from host Windows 8.1 not working. Got recommendation - reinstall VMWare tools. I do `VM->Reinstall VMWare Tools`. It mounts VMware Tools directory with files:

```
/media/ggg/VMware Tools$ ls
manifest.txt     VMwareTools-9.6.1-1378637.tar.gz  vmware-tools-upgrader-64
run_upgrader.sh  vmware-tools-upgrader-32
```

I suppose I must run `run_upgrader.sh`. But it is not executable and it is read only, so I can't make it executable using `chmod`.

How to reinstall VMWare tools?

Comment: The best way is to open a terminal window in Ubuntu, and execute `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools --install-suggests`  If you would rather use the tools shipped from VMWare, their website has instructions on how to execute the installations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the vmware instructions.See image below in case you missed or dismissed it. Extract the vmwaretoolsXXXX.tar.gz to your desktop for example and execute the vmware-install.pl in there. You will need sudo rights.

[image: VMWare Instruction]

Answer (score 0):

Yes CD-images are read-only.
Open a terminal in your VMwareTools and use bash to run:

```
bash run_upgrader.sh
```

if this failes do it sudo or other elevated security privileges:

```
sudo bash run_upgrader.sh
```

then it should install fine.

Comment: sudo bash run_upgrader.sh gives chmod: changing permissions of ‘./vmware-tools-upgrader-64’: Read-only file system

Comment: what is vmware-tools-upgrader-32 file? and how we can execute that? please help me.

Comment: @vico This is no problem, it tries to make it executable and fails, but it's already executable. The real problem (in my case) is that it hangs forever.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried [lawal's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/773380), the `vmware-install.pl` script returned an error:

> `open-vm-tools` packages are available from the OS vendor and VMware recommends using `open-vm-tools` packages. See [VMware support for `open-vm-tools`](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803) for more information.

Installing `open-vm-tools` using `sudo apt install open-vm-tools` worked for me.